# Why doesn't my new control appear if I pass the parent control to Create instead of assigning the Parent property?

Tags: delphi, lazarus, language-concepts

In Lazarus I'm trying this:

```
TabSaveButton := TButton.Create(nil);
with TabSaveButton do
  begin
    Parent:=NewTab;
    Width:=75;
    Height:= 25;
    Top:=530;
    Left:=715;
    Caption:='Save';
  end;
```

And it works. I.e., I get the button and it's clickable, and it is the child of a dynamically created tab sheet.

But the following does *not* show the button, nor errors:

```
TabSaveButton := TButton.Create(NewTab);
with TabSaveButton do
  begin
    Width:=75;
    Height:= 25;
    Top:=530;
    Left:=715;
    Caption:='Save';
  end;
```

1. Why does the second method not work?
2. Is this the same effect on both Lazarus and Delphi?

Comment: You're just missing `Parent` member.

Comment: @TLama: I bet the OP believes `Parent` and `Owner` is the same thing.

Comment: @Andreas, yeah, you're right, now I see. Deleting my comments...

Comment: @TLama +1 for your thought - Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The argument of `Create` sets the **owner** of the control. The owner is the component responsible for freeing the component in question. For instance, if you free a component, then all components owned by it are also freed. The **parent** is a completely different thing. It is the window (control) hosting the control in question.

There is no difference between Delphi and Lazarus here.

Comment: Thanks for that super-fast response. So from what you're saying they both act as a super-class to the control. And if I free parent OR owner, shouldn't the inner control get freed?

Comment: If you free the owner, the control is also freed. <del>If you free the parent, it is not freed. And it has no parent, so I would assume it becomes invisible.</del>

Comment: So is it correct to say that owner can be any object but parent is always a window control?

Comment: Almost. I think the parent has to be a `TComponent`. But it need not be a visual control, and even if it is, it need not be windowed. But of course, a parent has to be a window (a windowed control).

Comment: @Andreas, ad *If you free the parent, it is not freed*. No, even `Parent` free all of its children as well.

Comment: @TLama: OK, I guess that is a good thing. (To my defense, I can say that I just started a test project to find out!)

Comment: @TLama True in Delphi. Not true in Lazarus.

Comment: Itsols, neither the parent nor the owner acts as a "super-class" for the control. The term *superclass* already refers to something else. In the case of `TButton`, the superclass is `TCustomButton`. You can fetch that value at run time with the [`ClassParent`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.TObject.ClassParent) method. Parent, owner, and superclass are three entirely separate concepts.

Comment: @Tlama: it used to be that in Delphi freeing the parent did not free the children. That changed after D5, though I do not know exactly in which version.

Comment: @RobKennedy +1 for your inputs. Thanks for this explanation